# Javascript parameter getting passed as undefined

Tags: javascript, mongodb, asynchronous, mongoose, botkit

I'm currently using botkit-sms to send and receive texts, integrated with mongoose for storing my data. I want to get a user based on their phone number, so in my code I use a controller that is supposed to find the user by their phone number in the Mongoose User Schema. However, when getUserType is called, `phoneNumber` is undefined. Does anyone know how to fix this? I feel that it may have to do with Javascript's asynchronous nature, but am still getting comfortable with the language so am not completely sure.

```
controller.hears(['HELPME'], 'message_received', (bot, message) => {
  bot.startConversation(message, (err, convo) => {
    var phoneNumber = message.user
    console.log('phone number defined here' + phoneNumber)
    Users.getUserType((err, user, phoneNumber) => {
      console.log('not getting a user back here' + user.type)
    })
  })
})
```

And then in my user_controller I just have:

```
export const getUserType = (callback, phoneNumber) => {
  console.log('phone number is undefined here' + phoneNumber);
  User.findOne({ 'phoneNumber': phoneNumber }).exec(callback);
}
```

I'd appreciate any help! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are only passing in the callback function to `getUserType`, but `getUserType` accepts two arguments so,

change this:

```
Users.getUserType((err, user, phoneNumber) => {
  console.log('not getting a user back here' + user.type)
})
```

to

```
Users.getUserType((err, user, phoneNumber) => {
  console.log('not getting a user back here' + user.type)
}, phoneNumber)
```